# Problema com integridade referencial nas migrations (Laravel 5)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, migrations

Estou com um problema ao usar `onDelete('set null')` em uma chave estrangeira.Está retornando o erro:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint
>   `users_instituicoes_id_foreign` foreign key (`instituicoes_id`) 
>   references `instituicoes` (`id`) on delete set null)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Se eu troco o `set null` por `cascade` funciona.

Estou criando a migration assim:

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nome');
                $table->string('user')->unique();
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->integer('instituicoes_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('telefone')->nullable();
                $table->string('img')->default('default.png');
                $table->boolean('ativo');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();

            });
            Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table){
                $table->foreign('instituicoes_id')
                      ->references('id')
                      ->on('instituicoes')
                      ->onDelete('set null');
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Nessa linha

```
$table->integer('instituicoes_id')->unsigned();
```

adicione `nullable()`:

```
$table->integer('instituicoes_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

resposta obtida na pergunta  [SOEn - Laravel Schema onDelete set null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869072/laravel-schema-ondelete-set-null) na [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765839/6797930).

Depois desse ajuste pode rodar a parte `$table->foreign` com `->onDelete('SET NULL')` que vai funcionar.